# Error get method rest json

Tags: java, json, rest, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I've tried to make a rest app that returns me a list of recipes, the count method works but the when I try to get one or all of them it gives me this error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.json.bind.spi.JsonbProvider: Provider org.eclipse.yasson.JsonBindingProvider not found
```

I do have

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
            <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

in my `pom.xml`

Function looks like this

```
    @GET
    @Path("/{id : \\d+}")
    @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getBook(@PathParam("id") @Min(1) int id) {
        Recipe recipe = recipeRepository.findOneByID(id);

        if (recipe == null)
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();

        return Response.ok(recipe).build();
    }
```

This is the function returning the recipe by ID

```
public Recipe findOneByID(int id) {
        return entitymanager.find(Recipe.class, id);

    }
```

And the recipe has the following attributes

```
@Id
private int id;

private String complexity;

private int cookingTime;

private String description;

private int estimatedTime;

private String imageUrl;

private String information;

private boolean isPromoted;

private int preparationTime;

private float servings;

private String title;

private String type;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Allergen
@OneToMany(mappedBy="recipe")
private List<Allergen> allergens;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Ingredient
@OneToMany(mappedBy="recipe")
private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Mediaitem
@OneToMany(mappedBy="recipe")
private List<Mediaitem> mediaitems;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Nutritionvalue
@OneToMany(mappedBy="recipe")
private List<Nutritionvalue> nutritionvalues;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Step
@OneToMany(mappedBy="recipe")
private List<Step> steps;
```

Any hint would be a huge help. I've spent half a day trying to fix this

Comment: so you're trying to return a JSON to your local webservice? (glassfish default is port 8080 i think?) and you CAN return one result?

Comment: The count method works (how many recipes I have in my database) but when I try to get a recipe or all of them I get the error above

Comment: also, i am not seeing where you create/add to your json?

Comment: aha! i have an answer for ye then:) EDIT- so sorry, flash meeting in 30 mins i need to prep for. If it is not answered ill get to it later. Basically, youre not creating a json and adding to it. you're going to need to return a json string from your @id annotation

Comment: OK, I answered this because your JSON-B configuration seems to be wrong, but I can't see any JSON-B annotations or anything in your code. It doesn't look like you need it with the code you've pasted here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running this on [GlassFish 5.0-b11](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/releases/tag/5.0-b11) or higher, then you need to remove your dependency on Yasson (since Yasson is already included in GlassFish 5 nightly builds after `b11`), but you **should** specify a dependency on the JSON-B 1.0 API (and probably JSON-P 1.1 really) because there is no Java EE 8 umbrella dependency available yet to encompass all of the Java EE 8 specs.

Remove Yasson and add these:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note that they need to have `<scope>provided</scope>`, since GlassFish 5 is providing the implementation, and you don't want Maven to build the libraries into your app.

If you are using `GlassFish 5.0-b10` or lower, then you need to specify these same dependencies as well as the Yasson dependency in your pom.xml above, since Yasson is the implementation and that needs to be present:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
    <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have also explicitly added the `<scope>compile</scope>` here, since that is the default if no scope is provided. It's sometimes useful to be explicit about this since you may want to move this project to GlassFish 5 in the future and the scope would need to be changed and the Yasson dependency removed completely.

**Source**: http://json-b.net/getting-started.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm afraid that still won't do...

[Here](https://pastebin.com/HhET1DYS) is my pom.xlm if you wanna take a look

Comment: Is the error you are getting still the same or has it changed? You've got a lot of `compile` dependencies in there which are already provided in GlassFish and you're depending on both the full and Web profile of Java EE. For all of this you should only need the Java EE 7 full profile. As I said in my other comment, you're not actually using json-b in the code you pasted.

Comment: Also, are you sure you are using GlassFish 5?

Comment: It's the same error, and yes, I'm using glassfish 5.0.0b10. Anything you'd recommend adding/removing from the pom.xml?

Comment: I would take it right down to as little as possible. Do bear in mind also that GlassFish 5 is still not released, so you may just be hitting a bug. Is your code on GitHub or somewhere where I can take a look?

Comment: I don't have it on git, any idea where I can upload it and give it to you?

Also, I've tried downgrading to 4.1.0 and use the proper depedencies, now I get `The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request` yet the count method still works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149553/discussion-between-mike-and-hansewl).